# How to solve ElementNotInteractableException in Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, automation, automated-tests, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

I am using Firefox geckodriver.
I want to load a page and click on "I want it too button" 
which has id="J_cutBtn"

but I get error that

```
Element <div id="J_cutBtn" class="cut-btn"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

I tried to add the scroll down the page and also added Wait Until Object is clickable.

here is the Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", True)

path="C:/Users/Gupta Niwas/Downloads/Programming/College Projects/SEM 4/PBL SEM 4/geckodriver-v0.20.0-win64/geckodriver.exe"

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefox_profile,executable_path=path)



browser.get("https://mobile.mi.com/in/24hrMadness/task/?activityId=15&taskId=1026420&goodsId=4181200024&mi_channel=Social&mi_source=copyurl&mi_campaign=24hrMadness")
print(browser.title)
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 900)") 
browser.implicitly_wait(1000)
 WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"J_cutBtn")))
drop_btn=browser.find_element_by_id("J_cutBtn")
drop_btn.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `click()`:

```
drop_btn.click()
```

The button cannot be used with `.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)`